# Problems opening Facebook page from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, openurl

I'm going crazy trying to open my app's fan page in the Facebook app from my app. It works properly with Safari, but not the Facebook app.

I've read all the questions and answers here and they all point to this as the best way:

```
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://facebook.com/<my_app_name>"];
NSURL *facebookAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://profile/<my_uid_number"];

if( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: facebookAppURL] ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: facebookAppURL];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: facebookURL];
}
```

I found my page's UID by doing a search in my Facebook page. I've verified that it's the proper number by trying:

```
http://www.facebook.com/<my_uid_number>
```

in Safari. That works fine.

But no matter what I do, when I use the "fb://profile/ scheme, my app launches Facebook but then displays "Content Not Found".

Anyone out there have any ideas?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. I have had issue with the Facebook app on iOS, you might try restarting it or trying again another time.

Comment: Yeah, I tried restarting the app as well as the device. Still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is somehow with my page. I found another app's fan page and put their UID in my app and it works fine. So now I have to figure out how to tell Facebook that something is wrong with my profile page. Oy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with my Facebook page. The code above does work for every other Facebook page but my own. I've tried sending a bug report to Facebook, but that's like a letter to the President.

Comment: Wow. I went so crazy trying to figure this out. If I remember correctly, I believe reinstalling the Facebook app corrected the problem whatever it was. Unless the powers at Facebook read my bug report and fixed something without telling me. Hope that helps someone.